# Having trouble escaping quotes and braces

Tags: curl, escaping, command-prompt, quotes, curly-braces

I am trying to execute the following line in Command Prompt:

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "method" : "account_info", "params" : [ { "account" : "rHb9CJAWyB4rj91VRWn96DkukG4bwdtyTh"} ] }' http://s1.ripple.com:51234
```

However, I get the following:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: method
curl: (7) Failed connect to :80; No error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: account_info,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: params
curl: (7) Failed connect to :80; No error
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 2
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: account
curl: (7) Failed connect to :80; No error
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 35
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
unable to parse request
```

I am on Windows, and the error has to do with quotes, braces, and globbing. I tried escaping quotes by preceding them with a backslash, with no luck.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Do not use single quotes. Escape any double quotes within the string with a `\`.

```
curl -X POST -d "{ \"method\" : \"account_info\", \"params\" : [ { \"account\" : \"rHb9CJAWyB4rj91VRWn96DkukG4bwdtyTh\"} ] }" http://s1.ripple.com:51234
```

---

Window's `command.exe` doesn't seem to support single quotes. PowerShell does, but there are still some problems when using them, so the best solution is to not use them at all.

Comment: How could you insert a environment variable in there? Something like { \"account/": $ACCOUNT_KEY }

Answer (score 48):

You can use `curl -g` to turn off globbing:

```
curl -g -X POST -d '{ "method" : "account_info", "params" : [ { "account" : "rHb9CJAWyB4rj91VRWn96DkukG4bwdtyTh"} ] }' http://s1.ripple.com:51234
```

Easier than escaping all those brackets.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Escaping works, turning of globbing still gets me a 400 error. This could still a good answer in some situations, though.

Answer (score 4):

For windows users: you can download git bash for running the below curl command.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/subpage --include --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request "POST" --data '{"variable": "value"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the basic one to post something.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"username":"username", "password":"password"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/your_url/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above responses, it is important to note that data are specified in JSON format, which should require to specify `--header` as [Alok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9442090/alok-choudhary)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51205278/11573842).

It is also possible to define it in "url" format like this:

```
curl -X POST --data "method=account_info&params=[…]" http://s1.ripple.com:51234
```

and avoid specifying `--header "Content-Type…"`