# Grails Spring Security Rest 400 BAD REQUEST ERROR

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-spring-security

I have been trying to authenticate the grails spring security rest url `/api/login` using curl in windows. But unable to do so.
I've always ended up with `400 BAD REQUEST ERROR.`
These are my configuration

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
compile ":asset-pipeline:2.5.7"
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.5.4", {
    excludes: 'spring-security-core'
}
// plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
runtime "org.grails.plugins:mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1"
runtime ":cors:1.1.6"
```

====================================================================

**Config.groovy**

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.aes.apprater.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.aes.apprater.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.aes.apprater.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                ['permitAll'],
    '/index':           ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/project/**':         ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/appRater/**':        ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/mobilePlatform/**':  ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/**':               ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode=401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active=true
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\admin>curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"usernam
e":"xxxxx", "password":"xxxx"}' http://localhost:8080/xxxx-2.0/api/login
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 14
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 09:16:44 GMT
Connection: close
```

**DEBUG LOGS:**

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.6
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
.............................................
|Running Grails application
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security REST ...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST
2017-05-02 13:10:00,852 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Validated configuration attributes
2017-05-02 13:10:04,407 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - setHierarchy() - The following role hierarchy was set: 
2017-05-02 13:10:04,425 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain  - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/api/**'], [grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter@243ac73f, grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter@eef0bae, grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter@6fe7d42a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5d1a4acb, grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6924852d, grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter@5ca38348, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@73001b7b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@c0c6339]
2017-05-02 13:10:04,425 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain  - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/**'], [grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter@243ac73f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@146395d, grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter@eef0bae, grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@29600952, grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter@6fe7d42a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5d1a4acb, grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter@6003fbb6, grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6924852d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@25829af9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@c0c6339]
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8090/apprater-2.0
.2017-05-02 13:10:06,221 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2017-05-02 13:10:06,221 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-05-02 13:10:06,221 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
.2017-05-02 13:10:06,285 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-05-02 13:10:06,287 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2017-05-02 13:10:06,288 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
.2017-05-02 13:10:06,300 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
.2017-05-02 13:10:07,785 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-05-02 13:10:07,786 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper  - Skip invoking on
2017-05-02 13:10:07,786 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper  - Skip invoking on
2017-05-02 13:10:07,786 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper  - Skip invoking on
2017-05-02 13:10:07,788 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
2017-05-02 13:10:07,788 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2017-05-02 13:10:14,009 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] DEBUG matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/api/login'; against '/api/**'
2017-05-02 13:10:14,010 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/login at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
2017-05-02 13:10:14,010 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/login at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2017-05-02 13:10:14,010 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/login at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
```

Comment: How did you come to conclusion that you have to use `/api/login` url ? Does plugin not authenticate against `/j_spring_security_check` ?

Comment: I set enpoint as grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl='/api/login'

Comment: Okay. That's new for me. Wondering if you should really do that? Did you look in plugin code and assecertained that value you are setting is actually getting set ? how about confirming it with security app info plugin ?

Comment: This is what I am trying to implement.

https://giri-tech.blogspot.in/2016/06/create-secured-restful-api-app-with.html

I followed number of tutorials and I don't remember from where I got the code pasted in original question.

Comment: The link you posted uses security core 3.1.0 security plugin version whereas you are using 2.0.0. If you are using grails3, then why not latest plugin on spring security ?

Comment: don't look at the version. I am using grails 2 and compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.5.4". But ultimately I want the result...

Comment: grails 3 sucks when comes to changing themes

Comment: see this link also...
https://www.inshikos.com/blogs/80/dev/cors-enabled-rest-api-on-grails-for-cordova-apps-using-jwt-auth-tokens

Comment: Okay. Going back to basics. How about you turn on the logging for RequestHandler ? Code `400` means your request header is actually corrupted. You might want to look at headers again that are being sent in request ?

Comment: Also, how about using this curl command ? `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"j_usernam
e":"xxxxx", "j_password":"xxxx"}' http://localhost:8080/xxxx-2.0/api/login`   NOTE: j_username and j_password.

Comment: I was using username and password by changing usernameproperty. Let me try defaut j_username and j_password

Comment: same result...

C:\Users\admin>curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"j_usern
am e":"xxx", "j_password":"xxx"}' http://localhost:8090/xxx/api/login
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 22
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 07:40:14 GMT
Connection: close

Comment: Ohh man did not see `unmatched close brace/bracket` thing till now. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560858/command-prompt-having-trouble-escaping-quotes-and-braces This looks relevant specially here since you too are on windows.

Comment: same result....
C:\Users\admin>curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"j_user
nam e\":\"xxxx\", \"j_password\":\"xxxx\"}" http://localhost:8090/xxxx/api/login
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 08:44:27 GMT
Connection: close

Comment: You should try with `username` not `j_username`. Also this time you do not see `unmatched close brace/bracket` error ?! Also, use curl's `-vv` flag and post the output ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143161/discussion-between-arun-and-tyagi-akhilesh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after writing a test case in grails controller, it was the curl throwing 400 bad request error. There's nothing wrong with the configuration. The below test case proved it.

```
when: 'login with the admin'        
        RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()        
        def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:${serverPort}/xxx/api/login") { 
            accept('application/json')
            contentType('application/json')
            json {
                username = 'xxx'
                password = 'xxx'
            }
        }

        then:        
        resp.status == 200
        resp.json.roles.find { it == 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

        when:
        def accessToken = resp.json.access_token

        then:
        accessToken        

        when:
        resp = rest.get("http://localhost:${serverPort}/xxx/appRaterRest/index") {
            accept('application/json')
            header('Authorization', "Bearer ${accessToken}" ) 
        }

        then:        
        resp.status == 200
```